# AS3 gotoAndStop and if-else-if

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

i am trying to make a rotational view of a block in 6 frames with 1-4 being the facing 4 sides, and 5-6 being top and bottom. i have 4 arrows to "rotate" this view.
i am able to rotate 1-6 but unable to rotate from 5 & 6 back to 1-4.
this is my code. i am bad with AS, so pls be merciful with my mistakes..

```
btn_view_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewRight);
function viewRight(event: MouseEvent): void {

if (currentFrame == 1) {
    gotoAndStop(2);
} else if (currentFrame == 4) {
    gotoAndStop(1);
} else if (currentFrame == 5) {
    gotoAndStop(6);
} else if (currentFrame == 6) {
    gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
    nextFrame();
}
}
btn_view_top.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewTop);
function viewTop(event: MouseEvent): void {
if (currentFrame == 1, 2, 3, 4) {
    gotoAndStop(5);
} else if (currentFrame == 5, 6) {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you explain better the expected behavior?

Comment: hi, i am trying to make it go to the next frame when the btn_view_right is pressed and goes back to frame 1 after hitting frame 1 - a 360deg turn if you can visualize. then i have a btn_view_top where it will rotate the other axis where 1, 3, 5 and 6 makes another round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sintax that you use in the second function is not correct, you have to explictly use the or (||) operator.

try this code:

```
stop();
btn_view_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewRight);
function viewRight(event: MouseEvent): void {

if (currentFrame == 1) {
    gotoAndStop(2);
} else if (currentFrame == 4) {
    gotoAndStop(1);
} else if (currentFrame == 5) {
   gotoAndStop(6);
} else if (currentFrame == 6) {
   gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
   nextFrame();
}
}
btn_view_top.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewTop);
function viewTop(event: MouseEvent): void {

   if (currentFrame == 1 || currentFrame == 2 || currentFrame == 3 || currentFrame == 4) {
       gotoAndStop(5);
   } else if (currentFrame == 5 || currentFrame == 6) {
       gotoAndStop(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: great it worked! so i cant use comas like i thought it would work! thanks alot!

Comment: @tfcheng Consider also using a [`switch`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/conditionals.html#articlecontentAdobe_text_8) statement instead of many `if` ones ... And for more about AS3, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html).